# Abline does not draw line for plotting least regression line

Tags: r, plot, regression

Here is my code:

```
win.graph(width=4.875, height=2.5, pointsize=8)
plot(hours,type='o',ylab='y')
```

[image: time series plot]

However, when I try to add the least regression line into the plot which is included in the package called model1 from my textbook and the photo on my textbook successfully plotted the line and I just change the data source here.

```
abline(model1)
```

The code passed, but the line was not shown.

What is going on? I'm expect something like

[image: this]

Please help me, Thank you guys

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing some or all of the data in `hours`, and knowing what `model1` represents (a linear model perhaps?)

Comment: Do you have model1?